# use mongo db find an array element aggregate lookup on another collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have two collections in mongodb. they are related each other.

First collection structure is as follows :

```
semiproducts = [
  {
    _id: "64afad9eda7e337a51b304c8",
    name: "Cream",
    description: "One Degree",
    mater: [
      {
        mtNumber: 1000,
        id: "64afa9dcda7e337a51b30467",
      },
      {
        mtNumber: 150,
        id: "64afaa08da7e337a51b3046d",
      },
      {
        mtNumber: 250,
        id: "64afa9a4da7e337a51b3045e",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Second collection structure is as follows :

```
materials = [
  {
    _id: "64afaa08da7e337a51b3046d",
    name: "Un",
    type: "Gıda",
    amount: 1000,
    price: 13.5,
    description: "21",
    date: "2023-07-05T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "64afa9a4da7e337a51b3045e",
    name: "Toz Şeker",
    type: "Gıda",
    amount: 1000,
    price: 22,

    date: "2023-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "64afa9dcda7e337a51b30467",
    name: "Tereyağ",
    type: "Gıda",
    amount: 1000,
    price: 170,
    date: "2023-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
];
```

"id" in mater array first collection and "_id" in second collection related.

I need a stracture below, need total column in first collection, and values from second collection

```
semiproducts = [
  {
    _id: "64afad9eda7e337a51b304c8",
    name: "Cream",
    description: "One Degree",
    mater: [
      {
        mtNumber: 1000,
        id: "64afa9dcda7e337a51b30467",
      },
      {
        mtNumber: 150,
        id: "64afaa08da7e337a51b3046d",
      },
      {
        mtNumber: 250,
        id: "64afa9a4da7e337a51b3045e",
      },
    ],
> totalPrice: 1253 //sum of second collection material prices
  },
];
```

I tried the Aggregate Query with below structure but it didn't work as I wanted.

```
 [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "materials",
      let: { mat_id: "$mater.id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: ["$_id", "$$mat_id"],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "mat_info",
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      total: { $sum: "$mat_info.price" },
    },
  },
];
```

Thank you from now

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.semiproducts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "materials",
      localField: "mater.id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "mat"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalPrice: {
        $sum: "$mat.price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      description: 1,
      mater: 1,
      totalPrice: 1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/5H0D_PUdxXn

**totalPrice: 1253 //sum of second collection material prices**

I think your expected value is wrong. 170+22+13.5 = 205.5